# Books on exotic structures

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

The second half of the XX-th century has witnessed an explosion of results on the existence of smooth structures on topological manifolds. Following various sources in Wikipedia, a rough timeline goes like this (I am forgetting many other important results, but these are the ones I am most interested in).

- In 1952, Moise proved that topological 3-manifolds admit exactly one smooth structure
- In 1956, Milnor proved the existence of exotic 7-spheres, believing at first that they could be counterexamples to the generalized Poincaré conjecture
- He eventually would classify the exotic 7-spheres together with Kervaire in 1963
- In the meantime, Smale had proved the the generalized Poincaré conjecture in dimension $\geq 5$ in 1961, and the h-cobordism theorem, which would simplify Milnor's construction, in 1962
- In 1962, Stallings proved that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a single smooth structure for $n \neq 4$
- The generalized Poincaré conjecture in dimension 4 was then proved by Freedman in 1982. Together with Kirby, he also proved the existence of an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$
- The results of Donaldson on the intersection form of 4-manifolds of 1983, together with work by Freedman, could be used to construct examples of topological 4-manifolds without any smooth structure

As an algebraic geometer, I only know about these important developments from folklore, but I have never taken the time to study them in detail. I am trying to find a reference which would recap the whole story on exotic structures. So far I am aware of

- [Topology of 4-manifolds](https://archive.org/details/topologyof4manif0000free), Freedman and Quinn, 1990
- [The wild world of 4-manifolds](https://bookstore.ams.org/fourman), Scorpan, 2005
- [Differential Algebraic Topology: From Stratifolds to Exotic Spheres](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-110/), Kreck, 2010

The first two seem to be very specific on dimension 4, while the latter does not talk about dimension 4 at all, and also takes a rather non-standard approach through stratifolds.

Is there any book going through all (or most) of the above results?

Comment: Gompf and Stipsicz "4-manifolds and kirby calculus" is one of the better recent-ish 4-manifolds texts.   The field is still bubbling-along without any major landmark perspective, so a book hasn't really been fully needed.  I imagine in the near future someone will make something like Gompf-Stipsicz combined with the more recent observations coming from Floer theory.  But such a book does not exist, yet, as far as I know.

Comment: I think part of the issue is that your "exotic structure story" is really 3 different stories, split into the cases that the dimension is less than, equal to, or greater than 4.